# Tensor had NaN values

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu

TPU crashes at the same step while training giving error Tensor had NaN values.
The same code worked yesterday but without any modification it failed to work on a different TPU Device with number of cores.Can someone suggest how to fix this ?

Comment: Has the dataset changed too or is it only the TPU device? could you give some more information on what type of model are you training and the full error trace?

Comment: This problem solved on its own without any code changes. This only happens when I launch a new TPU instance. It automatically gets fixed the next day. This happened with me thrice. Weird